# ¿Cúal es el origen de "undefined" al mostrar una lista de json con javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

estoy en un proyecto tratando de aplicar unos conocimientos previos pero modificando unas cosas con el fin de ampliar aún más los conocimientos.

Tengo un archivo .json del cual quiero mostrar unos datos, ya conseguí mostrarlos solo que al mostrar la lista de características inicialmente se me muestra "undefined".

A continuación la estructura en html:

```
<div class="cuadricula">
                 <div id="carruselES">
                    <div class="MS-content">
                       <div class="item">
                          <img class="trj_img_cls" src="../RSC/COMING_SOON.jpg" alt="" id="imgESP1">
                          <div class="texto_trj">
                             <div class="nombre_producto">
                                <h2 id="ttlESP1">título</h2>
                             </div>
                             <div class="precio_producto">
                                <i class="icon-dollar"></i>
                                <label id="precioESP1">0.00</label>
                             </div>
                             <div class="caracteristicas">
                                <ul id="caractESP1"></ul>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div><!-- -->
</div>
```

Código en javascript:

```
window.onload = cargarDatos();

function cargarDatos() {
   const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open('GET','PRODUCTOS/esports.json',true);
   xhttp.send();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         let datos =JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         var i,resI,j,resJ,k,resK,l,resL = "";
         //console.log(datos);
         document.getElementById('imgESP1').src = datos.items[0].imagen;
         document.getElementById('ttlESP1').innerText = datos.items[0].titulo;
         document.getElementById('precioESP1').innerText = datos.items[0].precio;
         //console.log(datos.items[0].caract);
         for (i in datos.items[0].caract) {
             resI += datos.items[0].caract[i];
         }
         document.getElementById('caractESP1').innerHTML = resI;
      }
   }

}
```

y parte del contenido del archivo.json:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "imagen": "../RSC/ASUS_VIVOBOOK.jpg",
         "titulo": "prueba 1",
         "precio": "999.99",
         "caract": ["<li>hola</li>",
                    "<li>soy</li>",
                    "<li>una</li>",
                    "<li>prueba</li>"]
      },
      {
         "imagen": "../RSC/ASUS_VIVOBOOK.jpg",
         "titulo": "prueba 1",
         "precio": "999.99",
         "caract": ["<li>hola</li>",
                    "<li>soy</li>",
                    "<li>una</li>",
                    "<li>prueba</li>"]
      }
]
```

y el resultado de lo que intento es:

[image: resultado de la carga de datos]

No tengo idea de que puede originar que salga el "undefined". Alguien tiene idea de como solucionar esta parte?

Comment: Algo con lo que intentas algo no está... ¿en que línea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La variable `resI` no está inicializada, siendo su valor 'undefined', valor que arrastrará al agregarle mas valores.
La solución es fácil, inicializa la variable.
Código de ejemplo:

```js
var datos = {
   "items":[
      {
         "imagen": "../RSC/ASUS_VIVOBOOK.jpg",
         "titulo": "prueba 1",
         "precio": "999.99",
         "caract": ["<li>hola</li>",
                    "<li>soy</li>",
                    "<li>una</li>",
                    "<li>prueba</li>"]
      },
      {
         "imagen": "../RSC/ASUS_VIVOBOOK.jpg",
         "titulo": "prueba 1",
         "precio": "999.99",
         "caract": ["<li>hola</li>",
                    "<li>soy</li>",
                    "<li>una</li>",
                    "<li>prueba</li>"]
      }
    ]
};

     var i,resI,j,resJ,k,resK,l,resL = "";
         resI='';
     for (i in datos.items[0].caract) {
      resI += datos.items[0].caract[i];
     }
     document.getElementById('caractESP1').innerHTML = resI;
```

```html
<div id=caractESP1></div>
```

Comment: Tiene sentido, error de sintaxis por pensar que ya quedaban inicializadas todas  poniendo esa línea tal cual.